# Implement dropdown element in a table cell using HTML?

Tags: html, redcap

Just learned some basic forms of HTML and wanted to implement a dropdown menu into a table cell. My code below:

```
<tr>
        <th><input type="text" /></th>
        <th>
          <select>
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
          </select>
        </th>
</tr>
```

The input boxes are displayed perfectly, and dropdown only works when I test my snippet in Tryit Editor.

But when built into my REDCap project the dropdown snippet code is only shown as plain standard text? Screenshot attached. [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb7y3.png)  | As you can see, input fields also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dropdown menu in REDCap in a table, you will need to build a field that is a dropdown type field and then embed it into your table. You should also do the same with the standard text fields as REDCap will display them but it wont save any data entered into them.

Embed fields by creating them seperately to your table, then ente the variable name into the table in curly brackets {dropdown_field} you can add :icons to show the missing data, history and comment buttons next to the field. Like this {dropdown_field:icons}

```
<tr> {dropdown_field} </tr>
```